# Calculating Missing Weeks in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate the missing weeks in the data. Below image shows how is my existing data.

[image]

The below image shows what is expected results:I am trying to calculate "Calculated Calendar Week" and "Calculated week Diff"

[image]

Any help in achieving the desired results is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating another data set with all the missing weeks and did a right join!